# SQL Query for difference in days

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table

```
ID  LastName    FirstName   HireDate    TerminationDate  
1   Snow        John        2009-06-20  2016-01-01       
2   Drew        Nancy       2010-02-12  2017-10-04           
3   Spock       Captain     2012-03-14  null
```

I want to know the difference of days between hire and termination of every employee and if there is null it should accept it as todays date and calculate
Want to know th SQL Query for it

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_datediff.asp ?

Comment: It'd be nice to see more research shown. This question is just two very google-able issues in conjunction 1.) How to substitute value in case of NULL 2.) How to find the difference between two dates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following using [`DATEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff):

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(IFNULL(TerminationDate, NOW()), HireDate) AS diffDays 
FROM table_name
```

In case the `TerminationDate` is `NULL` you can use the [`IFNULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function with [`NOW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) as fallback value.

> **demo:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jWLk8XaCxApsHge3KtvbJK/0

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DATEDIFF(day, IsNull(hireDate, GETDATE()), IsNull(TerminationDate, GETDATE())) AS DateDiff;`

[DATEDIFF() explanation](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp)

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of DATEDIFF() function.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(IFNULL(TerminationDate, NOW), HireDate) FROM table_name
```

Here is an example - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_datediff.asp